# Whitespace below footer in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: Inspect element][image: The white space below footer]

I do not know how is that space coming. I do not want fixed footer but only want fixed navbar. My navbar is working fine but footer is having some white space below it.

```
body {
  padding-top: 4.5rem;
    min-height:100%;
}
.footer {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
    left: 0;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

This is the CSS for footer. I am using Bootstrap 4.

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav ..... #code for navbar
        </nav>          
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-6">
           <div class="card">
       ~~~~MY CONTENT~~~
           </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
        <footer class="footer">
          <div class="container">
            <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
          </div>
        </footer></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

However, when I change the CSS to position:fixed. It works fine but I do not want that. Thank you in advance.

[image: Updated screenshot]

Comment: Could you provide a full demo of your page?

Comment: I am sorry it won't be possible. But I will add few more details. Just a sec

Comment: If there actually is padding or margins going on, it likely isn't caused by what you have shown thus far.

Comment: Check it out now

Comment: Yeah the code provided doesn't recreate your issue. This does happen with a relative footer if the content of a page is thin, but your screenshot seems to suggest you had to scroll to get to the footer. Is this true?

Comment: OK i think what is going on. When the contents of page are large enough so that they need a scroll bar. Then my footer is fine and is stuck at the bottom in relative manner and everything is perfect. But when the contents are not enough that scoll bar is need. Then footer is not at the bottom but at the position after which my content ends.

Comment: Exactly. I was under the impression with your scrollbar in your screenshot you had to scroll to get to the footer. It sounds like that's not the case. It sounds like Adrian's answer is correct.

Comment: I have updated the screenshot. Could you tell me what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Your content element's height is not the screen's height. Therefore your footer will be like that, you can do it with JavaScript or just put content in your container.

Comment: I was thinking this, but there is a scrollbar present in the screenshot. I think it's possible there is actual whitespace after the footer.